# ModelBottomSheet does not hide on clicking scrim

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am working on building a bottom modal sheet. The problem is the sheet does not hide on clicking the scrim. The sheet is pretty straightforward and barebones, I have also tried using a modal bottom sheet with all the defaults and the same thing happens.

I was unable to reproduce the same issue outside of the project I am working on. I placed a bunch of breakpoints in an attempt to figure out what might be going wrong and found `onDismiss()` inside scrim(in `ModalBottomSheet.kt`) was not being called, which might be because the tap gesture is not getting detected I guess.

```kotlin
val dismissModifier = if (visible) {
    Modifier
        .pointerInput(onDismiss) { detectTapGestures { onDismiss() } }
        .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
            contentDescription = closeSheet
            onClick { onDismiss(); true }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while now, probably you have solved it already or compose has been updated since then but normally what you described happens when you set as `false` the `confirmValueChange` parameter of your `sheetState`.

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
                     initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded,
                     confirmValueChange = { false }
                 )
```

Switching to `true` would trigger `onDismiss`